# UIWebView iOS not display Yahoo confirm SMS Security

Tags: ios, uiwebview, yahoo-messenger

I try to develop an Application using Yahoo SDK.
When App show a webview with url :

> https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth/v2/request_auth?oauth_token=....

Then I input my username and account to login. Then webview displays Confirm SMS security view. But the webview do not display the "verify" button, like the Image below:
[image]

My webview also set **_webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;**

How do I resolve this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

correct the webview frame using

```
    [_webView setFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)];
```

Comment: I set webview frame already.
The problem is exactly UIWebView can not load the content of that URL.
But Safari can load it.

Answer (score 0):

Use yahoo mobile login URL for login and set the yahoo api URL in "done" parameter. It redirect to yahoo api for your app authorization.

```
https://login.yahoo.com/m?&.src=oauth&.lang=en-us&.intl=us&.done=https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth/v2/request_auth?oauth_token=.....
```